# Postgres: one-to-one join with duplicates and inequality matching

Tags: postgresql, join, query, subquery, pattern-matching

** Update: Fiddles now included https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=0c618e64c7fcd54c8781ed7d1ac540f0 and https://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/12053 **

I have two tables taken from two data sources, and need to try and match them. There are three requirements:

1. These data come from different sources, so there are no unique ids to match. Instead, it must be done on the basis of the data (a date, a price, a volume and a boolean).
2. Within each table, some rows have exactly the same data. However, there should be at most one match per row (not per distinct row; each one of the duplicates can be matched separately, up to one time)
3. For float (price) value within the match, I need to match the closest value within 0.1 of the thing it is matching to, rather than an exact match, because some values differ. Where the values differ, the merged value should be taken from the first table

The third requirement is what makes things complex. I can do all the former with a standard rank and full join (example code below), but I’m not sure how to match a row at most once with the within 0.1 constraint. I have tried rounding or flooring the numeric values so I can do a direct match, but it creates edge cases where a two values can be within 0.1 of each other, but on either side of the rounding cutoff, so they don’t match even though they should.

An example of the desired behaviour is below:

##### Table A:

| Date | Price | Confirmed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 50.6 | T |
| 2022-01-01 | 50.6 | T |
| 2022-01-01 | 50.55 | T |
| 2022-01-01 | 51 | T |
| 2022-01-01 | 51 | F |
| 2022-01-01 | 80 | F |

##### Table B:

| Date | Price | Confirmed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 50.64 | T |
| 2022-01-01 | 50.6 | T |
| 2022-01-01 | 50.6 | T |
| 2022-01-01 | 50.59 | T |
| 2022-01-01 | 51 | F |
| 2022-01-01 | 51.07 | T |
| 2022-01-01 | 12 | F |

##### Merged:

| Date | Price | Confirmed | In A | In B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 50.6 | T | T | T |
| 2022-01-01 | 50.6 | T | T | T |
| 2022-01-01 | 50.55 | T | T | T |
| 2022-01-01 | 50.6 | T | F | T |
| 2022-01-01 | 51 | F | T | T |
| 2022-01-01 | 51 | T | T | T |
| 2022-01-01 | 80 | F | T | F |
| 2022-01-01 | 12 | F | F | T |

##### Code so far (does not have working inequality match on price; only works on exact match):

```
SELECT COALESCE(a.date_val, b.date_val), COALESCE(a.price,b.price), COALESCE(a.confirmed, b.confirmed) FROM (
    SELECT date_val, price, confirmed, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY date_val, price, confirmed) AS r FROM table_a) a
    FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT date_val, price, confirmed, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY date_val, price, confirmed) AS r FROM table_b) b
    USING (date_val, price, confirmed, r)
);
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Consider creating a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14) with your tables' structures and sample data -- this will help people help you.

Comment: Sure thing - just added

Comment: Also made an SQLfiddle as well in case that helps. Although the one you shared seems better (I am indeed using postgresql 14 rather than 9.6)

Comment: What you describe is **not a deterministic algorithm**. With multiple duplicates on the `float` column, the result can depend on which rows from the other side are consumed first. I assume you really want a deterministic algorithm. Also, *"at most one match per row"* is the definition of "do whatever you like" if you don't define a primary table.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, if the outcome is determined by the order of consumption, presumably the algorithm can be made deterministic by including a standard ordering (e.g. from smallest to largest float value). I'm interested in applying this ordering criteria such that there is the smallest average discrepancy between matched rows.

Comment: @HarryE.: That addresses my first point. The 2nd is open. Plus, where to draw the line between overlapping ranges? Say, one table has prices `50, 50.49, 50.51, 60` and the other has `50.5`. That needs a very precise definition.

Comment: The choice should maximise the number of matches. If the number of matches is indifferent, it should default to the lower item.

So, if we had `49.9, 50.1` and the other `50, 50.2`, then we should match 49.9 with 50.1 and 50.2 with 50.2.

However, in your example, we should match 50.49 with 50.5, since 50.49 is lower.